# RealityKit – Why AnchorEntity position is always (x: 0, y: 0, z: 0)

Tags: swift, realitykit

I am using the following to to place an object on a plane. It works but the position of the anchor is always coming out to be 0,0,0 even though it is based on the raycast result.

```
let results = arView.raycast(from: tappedLocation, 
                         allowing: .estimatedPlane, 
                        alignment: .horizontal)

if let result = results.first {

    print(result.worldTransform)    // contains values 
    let anchor = AnchorEntity(raycastResult: result)
    print(anchor.position)          // why 0,0,0 
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Alternative approach

If `.init(raycastResult:)` doesn't work, use alternative approach with `.init(world:)` initializer.

```
fileprivate func raycaster() {
        
    guard let query = arView.makeRaycastQuery(from: arView.center,
                                          allowing: .existingPlaneInfinite,
                                         alignment: .horizontal)
    else { return }

    if let result = arView.session.raycast(query).first {

        let anchor = AnchorEntity(world: result.worldTransform)
        anchor.addChild(self.yourModel)
        arView.scene.anchors.append(anchor)
    }
}
```

Then:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    self.raycaster()
}
```

### Modifying your code

Also, you may modify your code adding these lines:

```
let anchor = AnchorEntity(raycastResult: result)
let transform = Transform(matrix: result.worldTransform)
anchor.transform = transform
```

Comment: For me if I use init(result) then I can add the model to the correct place. The only problem is that if I say anchor.position it is always 0,0,0. I will try your approach.

Comment: Using my approach, you can ALSO place the model to the correct place. And it will fix your issue.

Comment: And you can easily replace `arView.center` with `tappedLocation` (if you mean it).

Answer (score 4):

It seems that [position](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/hastransform/position) becomes zero when [anchor](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arraycastresult/3194593-anchor) is nil ([transform](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/hastransform/transform) becomes identity matrix).

If we call [raycast](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/arview/raycast(from:allowing:alignment:)) with [.existingPlaneGeometry](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arraycastquery/target/existingplanegeometry), [anchor](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arraycastresult/3194593-anchor) will not be nil.

[AnchorEntity](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/anchorentity) has **world space position** inside.
This is not included in [transform](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/entity/transform).

If we want to know **world space position**, we can calculate it by the following code. (It seems that there is no property that can be obtained...)

```swift
let anchorWorldTransform = anchorEntity.convert(transform: .identity, to: nil)
```